# How to use MongoDB with Kohana 3.3? using MangoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, kohana, php-mongodb

I'm trying to use MongoDB with Kohana using MangoDB. I've downloaded MangoDB which is a library to use MongoDB with Kohana https://github.com/Wouterrr/MangoDB

I know some of the questions here are very basic, but I need to ask because I couldn't find any documentation for MangoDB.

First, I don't know where to copy/paste the downloaded library.
Second, can I define the database at modules/database/config/database.php, probably something like:

```
...
'default' = array
(
   'type'   => 'mongodb',
   'connection' => array(
      'hostname' => 'no idea what to put here'
      'database' => 'example'
      'username' => 'no idea what to put here'
      'password' => 'no idea what to put here'
      'persistent' => 'no idea what to put here'
   ),
...
```

Third, what should I change at application/bootstrap.php, should I change anything there? Or what should I do exactly.

```
...
kohana::modules(array(
   'database' => MODPATH.'database',
   'orm' => MODPATH.'orm',
...
```

I would really appreciate any help or guidance to get started with this.

A similar question was asked before here: [How can I use MongoDB in Kohana?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426796/how-can-i-use-mongodb-in-kohana) and the best answer suggested not using MangoDB at all. But I think it is important to use an ORM/Active Record like library because it makes it easier to change the database in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to know how [Kohana's cascading file system](https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/files) and [Kohana modules](https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/modules) work. Basically when you have the same folder structure in `application`, `modules` and `system` than `application` overwrites `modules` and `modules` overwrites `system`. You should only write your own code in `application`.

Put the  MonogDB module in a dir called `mangodb` in the `modules` directory. So you should have some paths like this: `modules/mangodb/config` and `modules/mangodb/classes`.

Do not define anything in `modules/database/config/database.php`, instead copy and rename [this file](https://github.com/Wouterrr/MangoDB/blob/3.2/master/config/mangoDB.php) to `application/config/database.php`. Because the array key name is "default", you application should now use this file. Of course, change the config parameters to work with your own database.

Don't forget to enable the module in your `bootstrap.php`, I added the last module `mangodb` in this piece of code:

```
Kohana::modules(array(
    'auth'       => MODPATH.'auth',       // Basic authentication
    'cache'      => MODPATH.'cache',      // Caching with multiple backends
    'codebench'  => MODPATH.'codebench',  // Benchmarking tool
    'database'   => MODPATH.'database',   // Database access
    'image'      => MODPATH.'image',      // Image manipulation
    'orm'        => MODPATH.'orm',        // Object Relationship Mapping
    'oauth'      => MODPATH.'oauth',      // OAuth authentication
    'pagination' => MODPATH.'pagination', // Paging of results
    'unittest'   => MODPATH.'unittest',   // Unit testing
    'mangodb'  => MODPATH.'mangodb',  
    ));
```